# Поиск общего значения Laravel

Tags: php, поиск, laravel-5.7

Есть таблица.
id city_id region_id
1 2 3
2 3 3
3 1 3
4 5 2
5 5 2

В функцию приходят `city_id` 2 и 3
**Как быстро определить есть ли у них общий регион?**
В другой ситуации если прийдет `city_id` 2 и 5 например, то мне нужно будет проверить если у них общий регион, если нет, то создать новую запись с другим регион_айди.
Пока максимум чего получилось добиться этого

```
function check(int $first_city, int $second_city)
{
 $first_city_arr = Table::where('city_id', $first_city)->get();
 foreach($first_city_arr as $first){
  $check_region = Table::where('city_id', $second_city)->where('region_id', $first->region_id)->first();
  if($check_region){
   return 'error';
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: А код увидеть можно? А `::where` уже не в моде?

Comment: Что where? Table::where('city_id', 2)->get()? И что я буду делать дальше? В другую переменную запишу Table::where('city_id', 3)->get() и буду форыч в форыче сравнивать region_id === region_id??

Comment: В вашем приложении город может относиться к разным регионам?

Answer (score 2):

Если не хотите сильно нагружать бд, то можете попробовать сделать так. Получаем коллекцию городов, и сразу подключаем к ним регионы (внутри используется load, то есть всё в едином запросе к бд). Далее работаем только с коллекцией. Получаем регион для поиска и проверяем есть ли он в коллекции второго города! (Ну раз у Вас есть такая таблица которую Вы предоставили, то связь многие ко многим надеюсь у Вас настроена!) Код похож на Ваш, но с использование коллекций, а не запросов к базе данных.

```
$cities= Cities::find([$first_city, $second_city])->fresh('regions');
foreach ($cities[0]->regions as $key => $value) {
    if (count($cities[1]->regions ->whereIn('id', $value->id))) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Второй пример использование связующей таблицы как исходную. Работа то же через коллекцию:

```
$table= DB::table('city_region')
        ->select()
        ->whereIn('city_id', [$first_city, $second_city])
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('city_id');
foreach ($table[$first_city] as $key => $value) {
    if (count($table[$second_city]->whereIn('region_id', $value->region_id))) return true;
}
return false;
```